# Break is outside the loop python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

```
while True:
    x = raw_input()
    if x =="personal information": 
         print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
    elif x =="journal":
         name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
         completeName = "C:\\python\\" + name_of_file + ".txt"
         file1 = open(completeName , "w")
         toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")
         file1.write(toFile)
         file1.close()
else:
 break
```

the script keeps on giving me an error saying break is outside the loop are the indentations wrong?

Comment: You have to fix your indentation

Comment: also, you may regret not putting the **open(completeName, 'w')** thing in a ***try/catch OSError***... Specially if that 'completeName' is calculated based on user input... (Just sayin') ***:)***

Answer (score 5):

Yes, look at your post. Your `else` probably is meant to go with the `if` statement's indentation level.

`else` statements for `while` statements do entirely different things.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not an identation error. You normally "break" out of the loop. The else part in the while statement is not a loop construct. You will find the same error if you do

```
In [12]: if True:
   ....:    break

SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Comment: It is an indentation problem; OP clearly did not intend to use a `while: else:` construct, which most python programmers have never even heard of, and which wouldn't be useful here.