# How to break outside the loop?

Tags: python, progress-bar, break, maya

I am checking the progress bar's value and if it's 100, I want to exit so that the finished uploading doesn't get printed twice. I don't know why 100 shows up twice if I query the progress bar.

```
def callback(self,*args):
  cmds.progressBar('progbar', edit=True, step=1)
  if cmds.progressBar('progbar',q=True, progress=True)==100:
    print "Finished Uploading."
    break
```

I have found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730452/break-is-outside-the-loop-python) but the scenario in my case is slightly different...

Comment: There is no loop in this code sample. Is something else calling the callback function repeatedly? If you don't have control over the calling function, you could set a flag to avoid reporting 100 twice: finished = False def callback(self,*args): cmds.progressBar('progbar', edit=True, step=1) if finished == False and cmds.progressBar('progbar',q=True, progress=True)==100: print "Finished Uploading." finished = True

Comment: What does `cmds.progressBar` do?

Comment: @NickRetallack: looks like an answer to me...

Comment: Well darn, some moderator turned my answer into a comment.

Comment: @NickRetallack it did look like it should be a comment when it was only the first sentance.

Comment: @TZHX: I was sure Python needed 4 spaces to consider it an indent, but you're right, it doesn't; even 1 space will do. Removed the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a sufficient sample of your code in order to be able to help you. First of all, your callback() function contains a break statement even though there is actually no loop in this function.

In any case, I wrote the following sample to check and it actually only prints "Finished uploading" once, when 100 is reached.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.progressBar('progressBar') # initialise the progress bar

def callback():  
  # Begin loop from 0 to 100 - remember range(n) returns numbers from 0 (inclusive) to n (exclusive)
  for i in range(101):
      cmds.progressBar('progressBar', edit=True, step=1) # increase step by 1
      if (cmds.progressBar('progressBar',q=True, progress=True)==100):
          print "Finished Uploading."
          break
          # Theoretically, breaking is simply here so that you stop wasting iterations in some cases,
          # but it's not necessary for the printout, since we have only specified that the print will
          # happen when the progress value is equal to exactly 100.
          # Finally, if there is NO loop (like the code you pasted originally), then you shouldn't have
          # a break.

callback()
```

A possible reason for your problem is that you exceed 100 steps of progress for your progress bar, and that your progress bar's maximum value is 100. In this case, as you keep increasing the steps, the value will remain at 100 (which is the maximum) and therefore every time you query if it equals 100, it will return True.

Unfortunately, I can't answer anything more specific without more specific information from your part.